# getting command not found with "rec"

Tags: raspbian-stretch, usb-audio, microphone

I am trying to get my microphone set up correctly for a magic mirror, but something tells me it isnt yet as I cannot get the "rec" command to work. It gives "-bash: rec: command not found" when I try.

I also cannot get the arecord command to work without using the -D -plughw:1,0" parameter.

asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

`arecord -l`:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The *rec* command belongs to the *sox* package. You have to install that first.

Comment: My apologies, I was absolutely sure I had installed it but it obviously turned out not to be the case. It works, thanks!